# Issue with sending a string from raspberry pi to arduino using i2c

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c

I want to send multibyte integers,(eg. 1000,10000, etc) from raspberry pi to arduino. It can either be in the form of int or string(will convert it into integer on arduino's side) through i2c. Now, I am able to send data but only till 255, If I try to send 1000, the output on ARduino serial terminal will be 232 and not 1000. I tried to search over the internet for like 4-5 hours, but no luck. Can someone please guide me?

```py
import smbus
import time

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x04
a=1000
#a=str(a)
def writeString(a,b,c,d):
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, a, [b, c, d])
    return -1


while True:
    try:   
        writeString(1000,a,5,0)
        time.sleep(1)                    #delay one second

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        quit()
```

```
Arduino:
#include <Wire.h>

int data [4];
int x = 0;

void setup() {                                 

Serial.begin(9600);                        
Wire.begin(0x04);                          
Wire.onReceive(receiveData);               //callback for i2c. Jump to void recieveData() function when pi sends data

}

void loop () {

    delay(100);                            //Delay 0.1 seconds. Something for the arduino to do when it is not inside the reciveData() function. This also might be to prevent data collisions.

}

void receiveData(int byteCount) { 

   while(Wire.available()) {                 //Wire.available() returns the number of bytes available for retrieval with Wire.read(). Or it returns TRUE for values >0.
       data[x]=Wire.read();
       x++;
     }


     Serial.println("----");
     Serial.print(data[0]);
     Serial.print("\t");
     Serial.print(data[1]);
     Serial.print("\t");
     Serial.print(data[2]);
     Serial.print("\t");
     Serial.println(data[3]);
//     Serial.print("----");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I2C sends and receives BYTES. 1000 in hex is 0x3E8. 232 in hex is 0xE8. Only the low byte is sent.

Comment: Is there any way to send 1000? Either i2c or spi?

Comment: Even if the entire string is sent, It will be fine,I am unable to do that as well